# SSRS Cache Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssms

Attempting to cache my SSRS reports as referenced in

http://blogs.technet.com/b/rob/archive/2010/02/11/caching-ssrs-reports-for-performance.aspx

...I am to understand I need to set the processing options:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178821.aspx

...which seems to dictate there should be a dropdown here:

[image: ReportManagerDropdownMenuNotAvailable]

However, notice I hover over and nothing happens.

Could this be related to my previous installation SQL Express 2008 R2 with Advanced Services somehow failing to fully upgrade all the user options back when I upgraded to SQL Server Enterprise? I understand Express does not have the ability to cache reports per the documentation - but I am using Enterprise now.

Or am I just looking in the wrong place?

---

Basically, the SSRS Report Server page (See above Image), is still the crippled Express version - so the upgrade must have failed on that part. I tried backing up the instance, fully uninstalling SQL Server and all it's components, and re-installed from scratch. Still no love. What is going on?

Comment: Basically, the SSRS Report Server page (See above Image), is still the crippled Express version - so the upgrade must have failed on that part. I tried backing up the instance, fully uninstalling SQL Server and all it's components, and re-installed from scratch. Still no love. What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered: Even if you "Uninstall" SSRS from the Control Panel > Uninstall a Program, you must also do the following:

1. Manually remove/backup the databases ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB from the SQL Server. If we already had some reports deployed to Reporting Services, we would do a backup of the databases and reconnect after the new installation. If we want to set a clean Reporting Services without reports, we can just remove them using Management Studio.
2. Manually remove the virtual folders Reports and ReportServer from IIS (This is only for RS 2005. As you may know, RS 2008 doesn’t use IIS)
3. Manually remove the folder of the instance of Reporting Services (For example for RS 2008 would be something like C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER). This folder is not removed automatically and, if we don’t remove it manually, the configuration files will contain information about the old configuration and we might conserve old problem if they existed.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar. I believe I solved it by setting up the SSRS web under IIS? It's an option during the SSRS setup.

It gave me more control over the website configuration and I was able to manually remove it before re-installation.

Comment: Answered: Even if you "Uninstall" SSRS from the Control Panel > Uninstall a Program, you must also do the following: